AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' in some of the device
I am using python flask and mysql to run a simple login system. I get error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'" after i run the system and try to insert record into register form. However,it works when I used another laptop to do this action(record successfully inserted into database).
Both laptops use same database config and setting.Could anyone help me with this?
Setting in config.inc.php:
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';


Setting of database connection in app.py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = '8181shsh'

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'posturechecking'

mysql = MySQL(app)

What I have tried:
i set global privileges='ALL PRIVILEGES' AND GRANT='YES' for user='root' and host='127.0.0.1'
